# Why does gallium expand on solidification

Tags: molecular-structure, metal, crystal-structure, phase

I've heard that Ga exist as Ga2 molecules in its crystal lattice. Does that have anything to do with expansion of Ga while solidifying? Why and how does it actually expand?

Comment: Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Not following the guidance may lead to lack of satisfying answers, objections, question down-voting or even question closure.